# Carrierwave - Optimized Original Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, jpegoptim

I am trying to store one version of the image which is optimized using `jpegotim` but has the original resolution

Lot of images which are 10mb+ holds a lot of unnecessary data. Which when loaded is unnecessary on the client side.

Is there any settings i can choose that will allow me to do the same?

right now i am using the following settings

```
# Optimize the file size
  process :optimize => [{ quality: 90 }]

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [48, 48]
  end

  version :small do
    process :resize_to_fill => [128, 128]
  end

  version :large do
    process :resize_to_fill => [512, 512]
  end
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want different versions of the optimized file? You can do nested versions, so that the thumb, small and large are all processed from the optimized version. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: yea i want a different version but just a scaled down version

Comment: I'd say you make a version with optimize process, and nest the other version within the optimize version. DId you try this: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#adding-versions